# Add ignored file

Tags: plasticscm

`cm add file\that\is.ignored` results in `file\that\is.ignored has been excluded`. Is there a way to accomplish this without needing to add an exclusion to ignore.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but's there's no way to force the add operation for an ignored item.

You'll need to exclude it from the ignore.conf file and then add it.